# Does the google play store not provide updates for frozen apps?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, application-autoupdate, disable-app

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any other way to get updates to frozen apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35956/is-there-any-other-way-to-get-updates-to-frozen-apps)

I freeze problematic apps in hope of waiting for a better update. When frozen, the apps once *did* update like normally. I've turned on automatic updates in Google Play Store.

Now I've noticed that apps that are frozen does not seem to get updates.

Is this a problem with the way I freeze apps? I use Link2SD app to freeze apps.

Or is it because of the updated latest versions of Google Play Store doesn't allow updates for the frozen/disabled apps? (Google play store shows "Enable" button over the place of "open/update" for installed frozen apps.)

My Google Play Store version: 3.10.10

Comment: Frozen apps are basically "no longer there" (that is why you freeze them). Still there seems to be a way with updates, as your question suggests. I remember *Titanium Backup* having an option whether "market links" should be wiped when freezing an app, which seems to point to that direction: Maybe using TB, and *keep* the "market links" on Freeze would do the job -- maybe you give it a try (Link2SD requires root, so your device is rooted -- I cannot believe there's a rooted device w/o TB :)

Comment: @Izzy Market links are there. That is why google play can "see" frozen apps. I prefer Link2SD over TB. TB feels more heavy on my small phone.

Answer (score 4):

Based on one of the comments in an [AndroidPolice article](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/07/28/download-latest-google-play-store-v3-7-15/) about Google Play Store v3.7.15, you can't update frozen / disabled apps anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Just a bit more insight into this:

Since ICS, Google allows you to disable system apps via the applications menu - this is the same as freezing.

As such, Google Play needed to improve their system to allow them to detect 'Disabled' system apps that reside on the market - such as apps added their by OEM's.

As such, Google Play now detects frozen/disabled apps and doesn't allow you to update them until they are unfrozen/enabled.

Comment: I guess I'd have to wait for an update to the Play Store that hopefully fixes this..