# Is there any other way to get updates to frozen apps?

Tags: application-autoupdate, disable-app

This is in response to my question " [Does the google play store not provide updates for frozen apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35794/does-the-google-play-store-not-provide-updates-for-frozen-apps) ".

Since google play is *now* making it difficult, if not, impossible to find and update frozen apps automatically, I'd like to know of alternate ways to do so.

EDIT: Apps like 'App Update Notifier' and 'aTrackDog' **does** find the updates to the frozen apps! But **downloading** an update isn't possible since all these apps do is call the Google Play Store. I might need to sideload APKs or get the updated apps from web sources for now I guess..

Comment: There are update-tracking apps on the playstore. Did you try one of them? E.g. [aTrackDog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aTrackDog) or [App Update Notifier](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.goddchen.android.x.appupdate)? None of them explicitly mentions "frozen apps" in its description, so I cannot tell for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said, there is no way to update via Google Play if an app is frozen/disabled.

The only way to get the update from Google Play would be to unfreeze/enable it, but this isn't what you want.

The only other way to update an app would be to find out if the developer provides a spare APK to download - if they do then you can sideload this APK.

Otherwise, you *may* be able to do it using a 3rd party app store - however I don't like 3rd party app stores and don't use them, so cannot comment on this method.

So, in conclusion the only way to get updates to frozen apps is to:

- Downgrade your Google Play app
- Download the new APK if available

You can find an old Google Play APK via Google, but when you install it by copying it to the /system/app directory (overwrite the existing `vending.apk` file), make sure you freeze or delete the `marketupdater.apk` app, or the market will just update again.

Comment: +1 for simple downgrading instructions. Although the whole point of updating apps was to keep everything *including* the market updated. ;) Also, I'd be more than willing to try out 3rd party app stores that provide latest APKs..

Answer (score 0):

Use a 3rd party appstore I recommend [1Mobile Market](http://market.1mobile.com/) or [Aptoide](http://m.aptoide.com/installer?lang=EN) and install the app using those 3rd party appstores.

**Note:**
If you try to use those 3rd Market apps they might say that you need a certificate or you need to purchase them from the appstore. Just click outside the pop-up and carry on playing. This is not a problem with the frozen apps, but a problem with the app cerificate.